# sql question, alternative to if-else for this example?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
DECLARE @cityID bigint;
set @cityID = NULL
--set @cityID = 3

SELECT ID,
        Name,
        CityID,
        IsProvince
FROM TABLE t
    WHERE ISNULL(t.CityID, -1) = ISNULL(@cityID, -1)
```

whenever the `@cityID` is `NULL` the `t.CityID` is also `NULL` for that record.

Only one record can ever be true for `IsProvince`

Is there a way to check without doing the `if-else` clause if I want to do the following:

1) If the `@cityID` is `NULL`, then get the record whose `IsProvince` is `1`

2) If the `@cityID` is `NOT NULL` then get the record whose `CityID = @cityID`

Thanks,

Voodoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the WHERE:

```
DECLARE @cityID bigint;
set @cityID = NULL
--set @cityID = 3

SELECT ID,
        Name,
        CityID,
        IsProvince
FROM TABLE t
    WHERE (@cityID IS NULL AND t.CityID IS NULL AND IsProvince = 1)
          OR (t.CityID = @cityID)
```

This should work since anything = NULL always returns false.  The first clause should solve your #1, and the second solves #2.  I'm not sure if you really need the `t.CityID IS NULL` clause though, since your criteria for #1 doesn't mention it.

Does this make sense?

Comment: I was worried I didn't completely understand the need, hence asking if it made sense...

Comment: :) no, you got it. It was just one of these times where your brain hits a brick wall and you start to post your questions instead of thinking about for few minutes....